# Invalid Content Type after a POST request with httr

Tags: r, api, oauth-2.0, httr

I am trying to use the API named "Offres d'emploi v2" (Job vacancies) available from the French Public Employment Service (Pôle Emploi). The API is described [here](https://www.emploi-store-dev.fr/portail-developpeur-cms/home/catalogue-des-api/documentation-des-api/api/api-offres-demploi-v2.html). Using the API requires a token, and an authentification via OAuth v2, in a process described [here](https://www.emploi-store-dev.fr/portail-developpeur-cms/home/catalogue-des-api/documentation-des-api/utiliser-les-api/client-credentials-grant/etape-1---generer-un-access-toke.html).

I'm using R 3.5.0 and httr 1.3.1. First, I specify the request body. `eeid` and `eesec` are the identifier and the secret key delivered by Pôle Emploi when I registered.

```
require(jsonlite)
require(httr)

request_body <- list(
   grant_type = "client_credentials",
   client_id = eeid,
   client_secret = eesec,
   scope = paste(
      "api_offresdemploiv2",
      "o2dsoffre",
      paste0("application_",eeid,"%20api_offresdemploiv2"), sep = " "))
```

Then, I run the POST request:

```
result_auth <- POST(
    "https://entreprise.pole-emploi.fr/connexion/oauth2/access_token",
    realm = "/partenaire",
    body = request_body,
    add_headers('Content-Type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    )
result_auth
content(result_auth)
```

which returns an error about the content type:

```
> result_auth
Response [https://entreprise.pole-emploi.fr/connexion/oauth2/access_token]
  Date: 2018-09-29 14:33
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 70 B
> content(result_auth)
$error
[1] "invalid_request"

$error_description
[1] "Invalid Content Type"
```

I also tried to replace the line `add_headers('Content-Type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')` with `content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`, but I get the same error message.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, but what? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't add that header manually. Just add `encode = "form"` as a `POST` parameter.

Comment: @hrbrmstr That worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Roland. If hrbrmstr is too busy to draft a more complete answer then you can write up your own answer and mark it answered. This is perfectly acceptable behavior and adds value to the site for people who come looking for a similar question. (You probably should first do a search to make sure it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @42 Thanks. I was wondering if it was good behaviour, indeed. I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer following directly the comment by @hrbrmstr. Many thanks to him.

Instead of specifying the content type as a header, one should use the `encode = "form"` option in the `POST` function.

Note that `eeid` and `eesec` are the identifier and the secret key delivered by Pôle Emploi at registration. The complete script looks like this.

```
require(jsonlite)
require(httr)

request_body <- list(
    grant_type = "client_credentials",
    client_id = eeid,
    client_secret = eesec,
    scope = paste(
"api_offresdemploiv2",
"o2dsoffre",
paste0("application_",eeid), sep = " "))

result_auth <- POST(
    "https://entreprise.pole-emploi.fr/connexion/oauth2/access_token",
    query = list(realm = "/partenaire"),
    body = request_body,
    encode = "form"
    )
```

Comment: Hi @Roland, I'm able to get the authorization token as you worked out but a simple query like this will fail GET("https://api.emploi-store.fr/partenaire/offresdemploi/v2/offres/search",
    add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", key, sep = " ")),
    query = "range-0-49"). Any ideas?

Comment: Something like this works: 

 `search_body <- list(publieeDepuis = 1,     
                 commune = "34172",
                 domaine = "M11",
                 distance = 1);           
 search_url <- "https://api.emploi-store.fr/partenaire/offresdemploi/v2/offres/search";
 search_header <- c("Authorization" = paste("Bearer",bearer_token));
 result <- GET( url = search_url,
            config = add_headers(search_header),
            body = search_body)`

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I had to change paste0("application_",eeid,"%20api_offresdemploiv2") to just paste0("application_",eeid) when getting the authorization token. Not sure why ...

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks, I'll edit the answer.